Subsheaf of section supported on a closed
Let $i: Z \hookrightarrow X$ be a closed subscheme and $j: U = X \setminus Z \hookrightarrow X$ its complement. Let $M$ be a quasi-coeherent $\mathcal{O}_X-$module and $\Gamma_Z M \subseteq M$ the subsheaf of section with suport on Z. We have a exact sequence
$$  0 \rightarrow \Gamma_Z M \rightarrow M \rightarrow j_* j^* M$$
I want some conditions in order to $\Gamma_Z M = 0$. More precisely, if $X$ and $Z$ are smooth and $M$ is a $D_X-$module, then $\Gamma_Z M = 0 $ ?
Context/motivation:
If $M$ is  injective then its flabby and the last map is surjective. Thefore we have a distinguished triangle in derived category $D^b (\mathcal{O}_X)$
$$  R \Gamma_Z M \rightarrow M \rightarrow Rj_* (j^* M) \rightarrow +1 $$
It can be showed ([1], thm  1.7.1) that $R \Gamma_Z M = i_* (L i^*) M [-d]$ where $d = \dim(X) - \dim(Z)$ is the codimension. The example I have in mind is $Z$ a smooth curve, $X = Z^2$ and $i(Z)$ is the diagonal embedding.
It seems to be true that we have a exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow j_* j^* M \rightarrow i_* i^* M \rightarrow 0  $$
At least if $M = \omega_Z \boxtimes F$ (in that case, $i_*i^* M = i_* F$), but I dont understand why $\Gamma_ZM = 0$.
[1] Hotta, Takeuchi, Tanisaki - D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory

It seems to be true if X is integral and compact and M torsion free (e.g. locally free).  I am fine with that.

Why do you get in your example that $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow j_\ast j^\ast M $ is exact?
